# How to convert XML type data to Raw type data

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am working on something where I have to convert XML type data to Raw but I am not getting it.
I have tried converting the XML data to varchar2 and then using Cast_to_raw but it is showing hex to raw conversion error. Kindly let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Example describes conversion from xmltype to blob element. If you have to obtain raw value do the dbms_substr.

```
declare   
   dest_offset   integer;
   src_offset    integer;
   lang_context  integer;
   warning       varchar2(1000);
   v_xml_object   xmltype;
   v_blob           blob; 
   v_clob       clob;
begin
   --get example xmltype
   select dbms_xmlgen.getXmlType('select * from user_objects where rownum < 10') into v_xml_object from dual;
   --convert xmltype to clob
   v_clob := v_xml_object.getClobVal();   
   --initi variable
   dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_blob, FALSE); 
   dest_offset := 1;
   src_offset := 1;
   lang_context := 0;
   -- convert to a BLOB here:
   dbms_lob.converttoblob( v_blob, v_clob,    dbms_lob.getlength( v_clob ), dest_offset, src_offset, 0, lang_context, warning );
   dbms_output.put_line(warning);
   dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(v_blob,length(v_blob)));
end;
```